# Absolute Divergence & Divergence of a Sequence

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

If a sequence in absolute value $|a_n|$ diverges, then must $a_n$ also diverge?
For instance, might I prove that the sequence $z_n = n(1-\cos(\theta/n) - i\sin(\theta/n))$ diverges, by observing $z_n$ = $|n|\sqrt{(1-\cos(\theta/n))^2 + . (\sin(\theta/n))^2}$ $\rightarrow$ $\infty$?

Comment: Hint. $|\cdot |$ is continuous, so if $a_n$ converges ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes; you'll notice that the contrapositive is that if $a_n$ converges, $|a_n|$ must converge. So it is good enough to prove this. Let $a_n \to L$.

In particular, we have by convergence that for any positive $\epsilon > 0$, there is some $N$ such that $n > N \implies |a_n - L| < \epsilon$; but we see that by the triangle inequality, $||a_n| - |L|| \leq |a_n - L| < \epsilon$, so it must be that $|a_n| \to |L|$. So we win.